# How to move files in SDCard

Tags: java, android, storage

I'm currently running an app. The app is not released on the store, but distributed as an apk for users to download.
We have decided to release the renewed app on the Google Play Store. At the time of release, we are trying to implement a function to transfer data saved on the SD card from the old app to the new app, but I didn't know how to do it so I asked a question.

The functionality I am trying to implement is as follows.

- Added a data transfer button to the old app, and clicking the button will transfer data to the new app.
  ・Do not perform any migration operations using the new app.

We have confirmed that files can be moved using Storage Access Framework's DocumentsContract.moveDocument() on Android7 and above. However, the above method cannot be used on my Android 5 device, so I implemented it in a different way. However, I was told permission denied and could not migrate the data.

Below is part of the code I implemented.

The method that is performing the processing

```
void forTEST() {
        File fileDir = getExternalFilesDir(null);
        File[] fileDirs = getExternalFilesDirs(null);

        File appAExternalFileDir = null;
        for (File dir : fileDirs) {
            if ( dir != null && !fileDir.equals(dir) && Environment.isExternalStorageRemovable(dir)) {
                appAExternalFileDir = dir;
            }
        }

        if (appAExternalFileDir == null) return;

        String appAExternalFileDirPath = appAExternalFileDir.getAbsolutePath();
        Log.d("testlog", "externalFileDirPath:" + appAExternalFileDir.getAbsolutePath()); // externalFileDirPath:/storage/MicroSD/Android/data/com.example.testAppA/files
        Log.d("testlog", appAExternalFileDir.canRead() ? "true" : "false"); // true
        Log.d("testlog", appAExternalFileDir.canWrite() ? "true" : "false"); // true

        String appBExternalFileDirPath = 
        String appBExternalFileDirPath = appAExternalFileDirPath.replace("com.example.testAppA", "testAppB");
        File appBExternalFileDir = new File(appBExternalFileDirPath);
        Log.d("testlog", "externalFileDirPath:" + appBExternalFileDir.getAbsolutePath());// externalFileDirPath:/storage/MicroSD/Android/data/com.example.testAppB/files
        Log.d("testlog", appBExternalFileDir.canRead() ? "true" : "false"); // true
        Log.d("testlog", appBExternalFileDir.canWrite() ? "true" : "false"); // true

        File[] appAFiles = appAExternalFileDir.listFiles();
        for(int i=0; i<appAFiles.length; i++) {
            String fileName = appAFiles[i].getName();
            File destFile = new File(appBExternalFileDir, appAFiles[i].getName());

            moveFileToDest(appAFiles[i], destFile);

// I tried renameTo() but only found true/false, so I created moveFileToDest() and executed it.
// renameTo() returned false.
//            if (appAFiles[i].renameTo(destFile)) {
//                Log.d("testLog", "success to renameTo()");
//            } else {
//                Log.d("testlog", "failure to renameTo()");
//            }
        }
    }

    void moveFileToDest(File sourceFile, File destinationFile) {
        try {
            // When I performed the move process described below without creating a new file first, a FileNotFoundException occurred, so I added createNewFile().
            if (destinationFile.createNewFile()) { // throw java.io.IOException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
                Log.d("testlog", "create success!!");
            } else {
                Log.d("testlog", "create failed");
            }

            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(destinationFile);

            FileChannel sourceChannel = fis.getChannel();
            FileChannel destinationChannel = fos.getChannel();

            sourceChannel.transferTo(0, sourceChannel.size(), destinationChannel);

            sourceChannel.close();
            fis.close();
            destinationChannel.close();
            fos.close();

            sourceFile.delete();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

AndroidManifest.xml(Excerpt)

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

canRead() and canWrite() of appAExternalFileDir and appBExternalFileDir are both true.
But when I try to create a file inside appBExternalFileDir I get an IOException and it says Permission Denied.

what should i do.
I am glad if you could tell me.
(If there is any missing information, please let me know so I can add it)

Comment: The issue you're encountering is a consequence of Android's app sandboxing for external storage, especially on older Android versions. Apps have access to their own directory within the external storage, but they cannot write to another app's directory.

Comment: That's right.
However, file manager apps (ex. Cx File Manager) can manipulate directories of other apps even if they are not system apps. Do you know how this is done?

Comment: `to transfer data saved on the SD card from the old app to the new app` The files are on the removable micro sd card. They are there for both old and new app. So what is it what you wanna do as no data is lost.

Comment: `the button will transfer data to the new app. ` Impossible. One cannot transfer files to apps. One can instead copy and move files from one storage location to another one.

Comment: The new app is not an update of the old app? It has a different getPackageName() value?

Comment: `We have confirmed that files can be moved using Storage Access Framework's DocumentsContract.moveDocument() on Android7 and above. ` Then you did not test on Android 13+ devices as there you have not access to Android folder on removable micro sd card.

Comment: `String appBExternalFileDirPath = appAExternalFileDirPath.replace("com.example.testAppA", "testAppB");` ? That will never do.

Comment: `the above method cannot be used on my Android 5 device` Well with SAF on Android 5 devices you can read and write all files and directories in Android directory on a removable micro sd card. You do not need `DocumentsContract.moveDocument()` method to copy or move files but can do it in another way. Please elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

As since Android 4 KitKat removable micro sd cards are read only except for app specific directories on it you should let the new app copy files from old to new location.

On Android 5 apps can read all files in Android directory on card. But they can only write in their own specific files dir.